# convert Date to POSIXct from origin

Tags: r

I want to convert date to POSIXct format. In the code below I am converting 1601510400 to date format. I want opposite of it. I want to input `2020-10-01` and Output should be `1601510400`

```
as.Date(as.POSIXct(1601510400, origin = "1970-01-01"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `difftime` to get the interval between `a` and origin.

```
a <- as.Date(as.POSIXct(1601510400, origin = "1970-01-01"))

as.numeric(difftime(time1 = as.POSIXct(a, tz = "UTC"),
                    time2 = as.POSIXct("1970-01-01", tz = "UTC"),
                    units = "secs"))
```

```
[1] 1601510400
```